# After specifying android.hardware.faketouch the app still requires android.hardware.touchscreen?

Tags: android, hardware, requirements

I've been working on an app that originally had no touchscreen requirements specified in it's manifest file, so according to the documentation `android.hardware.touchscreen` is assumed. Because the app doesn't require advanced gestures, a device with a faketouch screen (`android.hardware.faketouch`) should also be able to run the app, so I added that requirement to the manifest file for an update.

However, the Android market still lists `android.hardware.touchscreen` as a requirement (as well as `android.hardware.faketouch`), and I still can't find the updated app in the market on a faketouch device (HTC Wildfire).

These are the permissions, requirements and libraries I specified:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"></uses-sdk>
```

Is this a problem (perhaps the market remembers old requirements, or perhaps the Google Maps library inserts a touchscreen requirement) or is it normal to see both listed when specifying faketouch?

Comment: Are there any docs as why Htc Wildfire is classified as a faketouch device? It has a capacitive touch screen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be too late but might help someone else looking for same problem

If you want the touchscreen feature to be optional add this to manifest:-

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```

otherwise it is implicitly taking touchscreen as required compulsarily based on some of your code

Comment: It was too late for the app I was working on, but I tried it for another app. It gave me an error because I was using SDK level 4 in that app, but strangely enough, that app did show up on the faketouch (HTC Wildfire) device. Meanwhile, I'll just mark this answer as correct until proven otherwise. :)

Comment: Well, yes, this is the correct answer, with one catch: if you then try and submit such app to Samsung App Store, the Store has a bug - it will mark all devices as uncompatible with your app. 
Google Play, Amazon App Store and Huawei App Gallery work all right in this respect and recognize that 'touchscreen false & faketouch true' means what it means...